# На яваскрипт как такое организовать? Добавить к переменной цифру или как-то еще

Tags: javascript

На яваскрипт как такое организовать

```
var locations_0 = [['Тула'],['Минск']];
var locations_1 = [['Орел'],['Варшава']];
var locations_2 = [['Новосибирск'],['Бургас']];
function initMap() {
for (var k = 0; k < 2; k++) {

    console.log(locations_?);

}
}
initMap();
```

Comment: Поместить в один массив.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно это структура типичного массива, когда объекты индексируются по номерам.

```js
var locations = [
    [['Тула'],['Минск']],
    [['Орел'],['Варшава']],
    [['Новосибирск'],['Бургас']]
]

function initMap() {
    for (var k in locations) {
        console.log(locations[k]);
    }
}
initMap();
```

В крайнем случае, если массивы не получается использоваться, можно достать их из области видимости, воспользовавшись [скобочным синтаксисом](https://learn.javascript.ru/object#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8).

```js
var locations_0 = [['Тула'],['Минск']];
var locations_1 = [['Орел'],['Варшава']];
var locations_2 = [['Новосибирск'],['Бургас']];

function initMap() {
    for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        console.log(this["locations_" + k]);
    }
}
initMap();
```

Answer (score -1):

Использовать [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```
for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    console.log(eval('locations_' + k));
}
```

Comment: Это даже хуже, чем написать просто `this["location_" + k]` и который сработает точно так же.

Comment: @AlexKrass Чем хуже?

Comment: А вы читали статью на которую же сами дали ссылку? В частности раздел "Accessing member properties"? Там написано, что не надо использовать ее для этих целей. Дело в том, что `eval()` является повышенным источником проблем и работает медленнее. Использовать `eval()` надо только в самом крайнем случае и с большой осторожностью. Несомненно Ваш код будет работать, но если есть возможность избежать `eval()`, избегайте его всегда.

Comment: @AlexKrass теперь уже прочитал. Спасибо :)

Comment: Если вы согласны, что ответ неправильный, то лучше его удалить. Потеряная репутации за минуса вернётся.